# Next.js does not recognize dynamic routes with square brackets names

Tags: javascript, next.js, dynamic-routing

[image]I have this directory structure:

```
 - pages 
   - api
     - products 
       - pro
         - [id].js
     - add.js
```

`[id].js`

```
import { upload, baseHandler } from 'helpers';
import { sequelize } from 'lib';
import { init, Suppliers, Products} from 'models';
import { supplierController, productController } from 'controllers';

const handler = baseHandler.get( async (req, res) => {
    const {
        query: { id, name },
        method,
      } = req

    init()

    res.status(400).json(id)
})
 
export default handler;

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

The static routes works fine but not the dynamic ones. I get this error when I try to access them
`error - Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.example.com`
which means Next.js does not add dynamic routes from the file system.

Comment: Can you please provide the full error stack?

Comment: there is no error stack exept  for that line : error - Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.example.com